# I want to revert to an earlier commit before a pull, but that commit is listed as the HEAD@{0}

Tags: git, bitbucket

Git beginner here. I made a git commit and then tried to push to origin, but got a message about the remote containing work I don't have locally, so I ran `git pull` and immediately realized that I had made a mistake, because my remote was set to the wrong repository.

So I had to undo the pull. I figured I could just do `git reset --keep HEAD@{1}` to revert to the commit I made just before I tried to push to origin, but when I run `git reflog`, it tells me that that commit is somehow at my HEAD, and HEAD@{1} is the pull from origin.

```
$ git reflog 
a98fsjs (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: This is what I was trying to push 
asd09jf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
asfasw9 HEAD@{2}: commit: Another previous commit
```

I know for a fact that I made the commit BEFORE I pulled, so why is the pull before the commit? Is there anything I can do to undo the pull?

Comment: It looks like you *did* do the reset already. The only thing that's odd is that `HEAD@{2}` should point to that commit as well.

Comment: @torek I didn't run the reset. Literally all that happened was I ran "git commit -m 'message'", then "git push origin master", then "git pull", then "git reflog".

Comment: Well, at this point I'm just as puzzled...

Answer (score 0):

Well that's embarrassing...I ran "git show " for the pull commit, and it turns out that was a previous pull from months ago. The current pull was in the middle of a merge and hadn't been committed yet. All I had to do was run "git merge --abort" and then "git reset HEAD@{0}" and the pull was undone.